# Mixing Matplotlib patches with polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data in polar coordinates, but I don't want the standard ticks, labels, axes, etc. that you get with the Matplotlib `polar()` function. All I want is the raw plot and nothing else, as I'm handling everything with manually drawn patches and lines.

Here are the options I've considered:

1) Drawing the data with `polar()`, hiding the superfluous stuff (with `ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)`, etc.) and then drawing my own axes (with `Line2D`, `Circle`, etc.). The problem is when I call `polar()` and subsequently add a `Circle` patch, it's drawn in polar coordinates and ends up looking like an infinity symbol. Also zooming doesn't seem to work with the `polar()` function.

2) Skip the `polar()` function and somehow make my own polar plot manually using Line2D. The problem is I don't know how to make Line2D draw in polar coordinates and haven't figured out how to use a transform to do that.

Any idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option #2 is probably the simplest, given what you want to do.  You would thus stay in rectangular coordinates, modify your function from polar to rectangular coordinates, and plot it with `plot()` (which is easier than using `Line2D').

The transformation of your polar function into a rectangular one can be done with:

```
def polar_to_rect(theta, r):
    return (r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta))
```

and the plotting can be done with:

```
def my_polar(theta, r, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    theta, r -- NumPy arrays with polar coordinates.
    """
    rect_coords = polar_to_rect(theta, r)
    pyplot.plot(rect_coords[0], rect_coords[1], *args, **kwargs)
    # You can customize the plot with additional arguments, or use `Line2D` on the points in rect_coords.
```

Comment: That indeed works, thanks.Out of curiosity though, anyone know how I could use Matplotlib's transform support to avoid the manual polar conversion?

Comment: @Roger. As far as I know, Transform supports linear operations, which this is not.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the ticks and the labels, try using

```
`matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0, width=0, labelbottom = False, labeltop = False, labelleft = False, labelright = False)`
```

From http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.polar

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment about using the matplotlib transforms...I used the following method to translate a polar plot into a polygon that I could draw on my cartesian/rectangular axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polarPlot = plt.subplot(111, polar = True)
# Create some dummy polar plot data
polarData = np.ones((360,2))
polarData[:,0] = np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi/360) * polarData[:,0]
# Use the polar plot axes transformation into cartesian coordinates
cartesianData = polarPlot.transProjection.transform(polarData)
```